# Acer laptop no power signs

Tags: power-supply, acer-aspire, laptop-repair

I have a 3-4 year old acer aspire 5742g  laptop.

The past month it has been misbehaving a bit.When I plugged in the power it would take about 5 mins to show any power signs (battery charging light) and while it didn't show power signs the power button doesn't work either.But now it doesn't seem to work at all.

I am looking for anything helpful as to why it does that weird behaviour

I have measuredvthe power output, the label says 19V and it gives 19,5V.

Also tried powering on with ac only and battery only none worked.

I have tried doing a power drain as some sites say 
but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to superuser. You've described the question well enough, but what have you tried to fix the problem? Have you tried another AC adapter? Remove the battery and try AC only? Any details like that would help improve your question.

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks, check above added what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its power control died. Not the battery, but the highvoltage electronics regulating the power distribution between the hw, the power supply and the battery. There is no simple repair for your problem. In your place I tried to buy somehow another bad laptop of the same type, but with another problem, and then "unify" them to a single, working one.

There is a little chance, that your laptop will work, if you entirely remove the battery and try to use from the power cord only. In this case your battery is extrem faulty (makes a short circuit).

Comment: Just to clarify, by accumulator, do you mean battery?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I fix it.

Comment: I have checked the ac power supply it gives normal power, so I assumed it was something with the laptop itself. Do you know if I can buy the parts that it needs from somewhere?

Comment: 1: If it is a battery, it gives DC. AC (=alternating current) is coming from the power cord. 2: most batteries give nearly their normal voltage even if they are already empty. You shouldn't measure the voltage, but the electric current (warn: measuring this means a nearly-short-circuit on your battery, but for a short time it is o.k.). 3: on ebay or on free shopping sites you can find practically everything, although the prices are fluctuating a lot. But in the case of an old bad laptop, probably the shipping cost will be bigger :) 4: there is a risiko that finally you will have 2 bad laptops.

Comment: In your place I buyed a second, bad laptop (cheapy), tried to unify the good parts in them, and if it doesn't work, I brought them in a service. It is the cost-optimal, minimal-risiko solution, although there is a little chance, that even the service won't be able to help you (this chance is really little, if they have spare parts).

Comment: @Peter_Horvath  thanks after leaving it plugged in it powered up for now. I will take a look if I can find a similar one